# Add image to each podcast series (or category) in headless WordPress instance

Tags: categories, rest-api, podcasting, headless

We have a WordPress instance that we query through it's API. Contents are `posts`, or `episodes` from a Podlove plug-in. We have four podcasts, though at the moment only one is set up in Podlove. We indicate the podcast an episode belongs to by adding a category.

Now we'd like to add a logo to each podcast series. We are considering two solutions:

- We could set up all podcasts in Podlove (which probably should have been done from the beginning). But as far as we know, there's wouldn't be a clean way to read it using the API.
- We could use the categories. At the moment we have four categories that we only use for the podcasts as well as a parent podcast category. But our first experiments with this plug-in also indicated that the category image is not included in the API and we couldn't find any plug-in that seems to be intended to be used with a headless Wordpress installation.

What would be the simplest or most standard solution for us to get a logo for each podcast?

Comment: Is the problem setting and reading the image over the REST API or getting those images then added into the podcasts' RSS feeds?

Comment: This is only about reading it over the API. It seems we already found a solution using the "Categories Images" plug-in combined with `register_rest_field()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be prudent to create a new custom taxonomy now named `podcast` in order to categorize your `episode`s separate from other content.

Whether using a custom `podcast` taxonomy or generic `category`s, taxonomies do not support attached media or featured images out of the box. You'll likely need to store a media attachment ID for the image in taxonomy meta-data, and either expose that meta to the REST API using [`register_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/) or add it as a field to the relevant response using [`register_rest_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/).

If podcast logos are some feature supported by the Podlove plugin/service, then you will need to consult their official support channels for how you should retrieve it via API.

Comment: Thanks, `register_rest_field()` seems to do what we need. Introducing additional taxonomies is an interesting idea as well as we're also looking for a way to filter for `category X AND category y` at the moment...